# action not found in Vuex store

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm following a course here:

https://thinkster.io/tutorials/nuxt-js-project/adding-authentication

I am working on adding authentication to my app and have login/logout buttons that partially work with firebase authentication. I can log in fine, but the issue is that when I'm logged in, the action in my Vuex store doesn't seem to run, therefore leaving the user logged in and the state not updating to display the logout button.

default.vue

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-navigation-drawer
      v-model="drawer"
      :mini-variant="miniVariant"
      :clipped="clipped"
      fixed
      app
    >
      <v-list>
        <v-list-item
          v-for="(item, i) in items"
          :key="i"
          :to="item.to"
          router
          exact
        >
          <v-list-item-action>
            <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
          </v-list-item-action>
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title v-text="item.title" />
          </v-list-item-content>

        </v-list-item>
        <button v-if="!mySession" @click="login">Login</button>
        <button v-else @click="logout">Logout</button>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
    <!-- <v-toolbar fixed app :clipped-left="clipped">
      <v-toolbar-side-icon @click="drawer = !drawer"></v-toolbar-side-icon>
      <v-tool-bar-title v-text="title"></v-tool-bar-title>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-toolbar-items>
        <v-btn @click="login">Login</v-btn>
        <v-btn @click="logout">Logout</v-btn>
      </v-toolbar-items>
    </v-toolbar> -->
    <v-app-bar
      :clipped-left="clipped"
      fixed
      app
    >
      <v-app-bar-nav-icon @click.stop="drawer = !drawer" />

      <v-btn
        icon
        @click.stop="clipped = !clipped"
      >
        <v-icon>mdi-application</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
      <v-btn
        icon
        @click.stop="fixed = !fixed"
      >
        <v-icon>mdi-minus</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
      <v-toolbar-title v-text="title" />
      <v-spacer />
    </v-app-bar>
    <v-content>
      <v-container>
        <nuxt />
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
    <v-navigation-drawer
      v-model="rightDrawer"
      :right="right"
      temporary
      fixed
    >
      <v-list>
        <v-list-item @click.native="right = !right">
          <v-list-item-action>
            <v-icon light>
              mdi-repeat
            </v-icon>
          </v-list-item-action>
          <v-list-item-title>Switch drawer (click me)</v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-footer
      :fixed="fixed"
      app
    >
      <span>&copy; 2019</span>
    </v-footer>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import {db} from '@/plugins/firebase'
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'

export default {
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('setSession');
  },
  data () {
    return {
      clipped: false,
      drawer: false,
      fixed: false,
      items: [
        {
          icon: 'mdi-apps',
          title: 'Welcome',
          to: '/'
        },
        {
          icon: 'cart',
          title: 'Checkout',
          to: '/checkout'
        }
      ],
      miniVariant: false,
      right: true,
      rightDrawer: false,
      title: 'Vuetify.js'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    login() {
      console.log('login');
      let provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
      firebase.auth()
      .signInWithPopup(provider)
      .then(function(result) {
        console.log('signed in');
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      })
    },
    logout() {
       console.log('logout');
       firebase.auth()
       .signOut()
       .then(() => {
         console.log('sign out')
       }).catch((error) => {
         console.log(error)
       })
    }
  },
  computed: {
    mySession() {
      return this.$store.getters.session;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

store/index.js

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'

const createStore = () => {
  return new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        session: false
    },
    mutations: {
        SET_SESSION(state, session) {
            state.session = session;
        }
    },
    getters: {
        session: state => state.session
    },
    actions: {
        setSession({commit}) {
            firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
                console.log(user);
                console.log('change');
                commit('SET_SESSION', user || false);
            })
        }
    }
  })
}

export default createStore
```

in console I am getting an error message that says:

"`[vuex] unknown action type: setSession`"

To reiterate, I can login using Google oauth, but when logged in, the state does not change and the logout button does not appear.

Thanks for the help!

**Update:**

Well now I'm *extra* confused. I did push updates 15 mins ago but for some reason my store/index.js file is outdated and isn't updating/saving? I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

When looking at my store/index.js file on Github, it shows the default template:
https://github.com/SIeep/US-kratom/blob/master/US-Kratom/store/index.js

But what I have, and what was just copied from the course I'm taking is:

```
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';

const createStore = () => {
  return new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
      session: false,
      products: []
    },
    mutations: {
      SET_SESSION(state, session) {
        state.session = session;
      },
      SET_PRODUCT(state, product) {
        state.products = product;
      }
    },
    getters: {
      session: state => state.session,
      products: state => state.products
    },
    actions: {
      setSession({ commit }) {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
          commit('SET_SESSION', user || false);
        });
      },
      setProduct({ commit }, products) {
        commit('SET_PRODUCT', products);
      }
    }
  });
};

export default createStore;
```

I am saving the file and everything but it's not updating on Github which is obviously the issue with my app as well.

Comment: Could you show us where you're calling `createStore`? Is this your only store? Have you checked in the Vue Devtools to see what that thinks is going on?

Comment: Hi! I don't believe I am calling ```createStore``` anywhere. This is my only store. I did check Vue Devtools. 

If it helps any, here is a link to the repo:

https://github.com/SIeep/US-kratom

Comment: I hadn't clocked that you were using Nuxt. Not calling `createStore` should be fine, Nuxt will do that for you, though I would note that you're using a deprecated way of creating the store, https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store#classic-mode. Nuxt requires you to use a function to define the `state`, though I don't think that explains your problem. In the Vue Devtools are you able to see the state you're expecting? The repo link doesn't seem to include the code above so I'm not sure what to do with that. I'm starting to think you just need to check everything is saved and restart your dev server.

Comment: No worries! Thanks for looking! This is very helpful and wouldn't be surprised if it's because of the deprecation you mentioned. When I look in Vue DevTools under Vuex, it shows the current state of the default counter. It seems like ```createStore``` isn't working at all, right? I apologize for being so new.

I also just pushed updates to Github so please feel free to reproduce the issue with my code.

I did restart my dev server with no luck :(

Comment: I still don't see the new store code on GitHub. Currently everything you've said suggests that we're getting an older version of that file. Please check that you've saved that file and restart your dev server to make sure the new file is picked up by the build. Access it using an incognito window to try to avoid any browser caching problems.

Comment: Hey, I really really appreciate your help with this! I'm not sure why, but my store/index.js file isn't updating. I did push updates to github a while ago but the store/index.js file shows the original template before I copied the code from the course I am currently taking.

Why would this file not be updating when I save and restart my dev server? It's not even updating to Github. gr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erik from Thinkster.io ended up fixing the code for me. Update is here:

[https://github.com/SIeep/US-kratom/commit/bd55deacadfc065edc7df9c1365ae832a32b9b43][1]